# Constraint on generic type cannot be used in IEnumerable?

Tags: c#

There probably is a question on this already, but I wasn't able to come up with the search terms to find an answer..

I'm probably missing something obvious here, but why am I not allowed to do the following, which gives the error:

> "Argument 1: cannot convert from `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TType>` to `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable< Test.A>`"

whilst making the call to DoSomething?

```
public interface A
{
    void Foo();
}

public class B : A
{
    public void Foo()
    {
    }
}

class Test<TType> where TType : A
{
    public Test(IEnumerable<TType> testTypes)
    {
        DoSomething(testTypes);
    }

    void DoSomething(IEnumerable<A> someAs)
    {
    }
}
```

whilst it is, of course, OK to do this:

```
class Test
{
    public Test(IEnumerable<B> testTypes)
    {
        DoSomething(testTypes);
    }

    void DoSomething(IEnumerable<A> someAs)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Variance supported only for reference types. If `TTypes` is `struct`, then `IEnumerable<TType>` can not be casted to `IEnumerable<A>`. If you add additional `class` constraint to `TType`, then cast will be allowed.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense. Not a huge problem for me code wise, I was just curious when I tried to do it and got the error. Edit: saw that you edited your response to suggest use of class in the where clause - thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Variance works only for reference types. In your code `TType` can also be a value type. If you add a `class` constraint, the code will compile

```
class Test<TType> where TType : class, A
{
    public Test(IEnumerable<TType> testTypes)
    {
        DoSomething(testTypes);
    }

    void DoSomething(IEnumerable<A> someAs)
    {
    }
}
```

You can find a detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056888/why-does-variance-in-net-4-only-support-reference-types)

Comment: And variance works only with reference types because value types (struct) cannot inherit from another type and thus can variance cannot really apply.

Comment: @PeterRitchie value types can implement interfaces, so variance can apply. But casting a value type to an interface causes boxing, which changes the representation to reference.

Comment: @JakubLortz structs can *implement* interfaces, they don't *derive* from interfaces.  Variance deals with *more derived* types (covariance) and *less  derived* types.  Without the ability to derive from a base type, variance does not really apply.  Independent of the fact that value types are boxed...

Comment: @PeterRitchie Variance does work with interfaces. What matters is the ability to safely cast between types. It doesn't matter if the types are 2 classes, class and interface or 2 interfaces.